# It is possible to allow write permission to multiple users on the Quickblox framework?

Tags: quickblox

I'm considering to integrate Quickblox backend to my mobile app.
But i do need to allow multiple users to have write access to same objects (both in custom and content modules).

Is it possible?

Thanks,
Maicon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuickBlox released iOS SDK 1.7 with Permissions API - http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios#Permissions

REST API documentation http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Permissions

Now you can do this like a piece of cake

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, but there is workaround: 
create one single SuperUser whose credentials will be used by every user when editing a object